# how to look for these kind of infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$={${\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{a_i}{5^i}: a_i= 0,1,2,3,4}$} contained in $R$.

then

1) A is finite set.

2) A is countable infinite

3) A is uncountable but does not contain an open interval

4) A contains an open interval

how to find out which one holds?

one construction of this kind is i know in cantor set. is there any relation between the two?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $x\in[0,5]$, and imagine writing out $x$ in base five. Each digit will be $0,1,2,3$, or $4$, and you’ll have one digit to the left of the decimal point, so you’ll have

$$x=a_0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots_{\text{five}}$$

for some sequence $\langle a_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of integers from the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Now what does that base five ‘decimal’ actually represent?

$$x=a_0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots_{\text{five}}=a_0+\frac{a_1}5+\frac{a_2}{5^2}+\ldots=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{a_k}{5^k}\;.$$

Can you answer the question now?

Comment: @user290972: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

hint: look at the $5$-base representation of the numbers in [0,1]